# Get the nearest location from start location

Tags: java, rest, here-api

I want to get the nearest location of predefined locations to the start location.

for example :
Post https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/
geocode

Body:

```
{
from:{
counrtyCode:"US",
city:"NewYouk",
Postcode:"55555"
},
to:[
{
counrtyCode:"US",
city:"NewYouk",
Postcode:"66666"
},
{
counrtyCode:"US",
city:"NewYouk",
Postcode:"77777"
}
]
```

I want to check which one in the TO List is the nearest to The FROM location.
Do we have something like this in HERE Rest API ?

Comment: there should be some api to get gps cordinates given the city name.

Comment: I think there is an API to get gps coordinates but how to get the nearest location from coordinate detail?

Comment: just calculate the distance with each other location, with some formula(again, there must be exsisting algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like geocoordinate1.distanceTo(geocoordinate2) to get the distance between any two geocoordinates and do this for a list of geocoordinates and take the least one.